# TestFlightから製品版へ内部データは受け継がれるのでしょうか?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

CoreDataを使って、ユーザーが入力した情報を保存して表示するアプリを作りました。
100円で配布するつもりです。

TestFlightを使ってリリースまでの期間にテスターを募集するのですが
テスト期間が終わったユーザーが継続してアプリを使いたい場合は製品版を購入して使用という処理になるのでしょうか?アップデートしたら製品版になったりするのでしょうか?
テスト期間が終わって製品版に移行した場合、ベータ版で入力したデータは製品版に引き継がれるのでしょうか？

TestFlightを導入するのが初めてなので経験者の方からすれば笑われるような
初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、調べても出てこなかったので
もしご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: iOSアプリにはアップデートして購入という概念が無かったような気がします。プロビジョニングプロファイルも別になると思いますし、多分無理そう。

Comment: @M.I.A そうですか。ありがとうございます！どうしてもわからなかったので大変参考になりました。